# Can't boot to recovery neither rom

Tags: bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-g-4g

I made a mistake while trying to flash an stock rom in my XT1644. While unlocking bootloader, I didn't realize I had to check the "allow OEM unlock" in developer options. When I thought unlocking had gone good, I started flashing manually a stock update, and everything failed. Now, I can't boot into recovery nor flash a recover nor unlock correctly bootloader, since "allow OEM unlock" still appears on screen.

Tried using RSD Lite, but doesn't work.

How can I unlock my device without checking the "allow OEM unlock" since I have no OS nor recovery?

Comment: You can't unlock it without that turned on. You need to get the proper stock rom and flash via fastboot.

Comment: I know, and that's precisely the problem, that I can't boot anything since I broke it all. Should I do hardbrick maybe?

Comment: If it doesn't show up as a QLoad device, you can't... it's not hard-bricked. You need to get the stock ROM flashed with fastboot. Are you doing it manually with `fastboot oem fb_mode_set`, flash bootloader and gpt.bin, then `fastboot reboot-bootloader` and continue through rest of options? If that won't work, I got nothing. What did you flash incorrect? If it was a bootloader or partition table (gpt.bin) you may have perma-bricked it.

Comment: I haven't done `fastboot reboot-bootloader`, but always doing `fastboot flash partition gpt` and `fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img` fails. I just simply thought the device was unlocked and flashed gpt.bin, not being able to boot recovery neither rom since that.

Comment: Fails? What is the error message?

Comment: `(bootloader) Preflash validation failed`. In the cellphone you can see the `oem_locked` message, and when I try to unlock with the unlock key, the phone says I need to "allow OEM unlock", but I can't.

Comment: It's bricked. Happed to me also.
http://www.stechguide.com/download-stock-firmware-of-moto-g4-and-g4-plus/
Follow this guide.
It may help.

Comment: "Preflash validation failed" means the factory image you are using is older than your current software... you cannot downgrade, you need to find the same or newer firmware image that matches your device.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You need to wipe everything so that system does not interfere in the process of flashing a new rom.

fastboot -> fastboot device.
it should show your device.
keep following ready : XT1644 Stock Marshmallow/Nougat Image Sparsechunk ZIP. I will post link in next edit.
Keep commands ready. 
When flashing, omit flashing OEM command. start flashing with Partition.gpt.